# Hide responses of model annotations in production asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Hi all I use `[Required]` among other annotations. When the application is in production I would like to change the default messages or better yet send a simple http response.

I noticed that some people do this
`[Required(ErrorMessage = "res")]` I have many fields. I don't want to do them manually one by one, but I was wondering how is it possible to do this even though `Required` has a single no arguments constructor?

Thank you

Comment: Your tags didnt  mention which framework, so we have to assume the latest, which does have a `ErrorMessage` argument in a constructor: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute?view=net-6.0

Comment: But in the link you listed there is only one constructor for the class. What feature of C# makes this possible. Thanks @mxmissile

Comment: That's just inheritance, `Required` is derived from `ValidationAttribute`, which does have a constructor that takes the string. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 0):

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;

namespace MyCoolApplication
{
    public class ValidationActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
        {
            if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                context.Result = ((ControllerBase)context.Controller).Problem();
            }
        }
    }
}
```